# how to pass username password from windows application to web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i want to call web api from windows application.

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have?

Comment: i ddint get any idea to how to solve this problem. i need help. but i am getting data to grid view i did this. but how can i check logins from win form?

Answer (score 3):

You could use WebRequest to call your WebApi. Something on these lines. Its difficult to understand what you exactly want. When asking question, try to tell in detail what you have already tried and what fails. This is not a coding service.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://webapiaddress");
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Edit after more information:

You could use something on these lines:

```
    public async Task<TResult> GetAsync<TResult>(string uriString) where TResult : class
    {
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        using (var client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Log.Error(response.ReasonPhrase);
                return default(TResult);
            }
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
        }
    }

    private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var username = // get your username
        var password = // get your password
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
```

Comment: using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(path2))
         {
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             {
  var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); dtGrid.datasource=data; }}}. before executing this i need to check user logins. means i want to pass useri, passwrd to web api ,if user is valid then i wll show my gridview form.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objuser), Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

 stringContent.Headers.Add("j_username", objuser.j_username);
 stringContent.Headers.Add("j_password", objuser.j_password); 
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(@"URL"?j_username=" + objuser.j_username + "&j_password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(objuser.j_password), stringContent).Result;
 string path2 = "URL/getall";

 var response1 = await client.GetAsync(path2);

  var data = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     if (true)
        {
     var data2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(data);
         }
```